# Removing ".on" Click Event in jQuery using 'selector;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery's ".on" to attach a click even to a "More Items" button. This event may get re-attached multiple time due to the way our script processes.

I want to prevent multiple events from firing when this button is clicked. I'm actually attaching the event to "document" and using a selector to target the button. Again this is because of reloads and ajax calls I keep the event on "document" so it's never lost.

Below is my code:

```
  // Removes previous events 
  $(document).off('click','.moreItems');

 // Attached new event
  $(document).on('click','.moreItems', function(event) {
    ... do stuff ....
  });
```

I've scoured stack voerflow for an answer but nothing helped. Everything talks about removing the event from the initial object ("document" in this case) but never using a selector (that I could find).

Thanks!

Comment: _"This event may get re-attached multiple time due to the way our script processes."_ - I'd say this is poor programming, I see no reason for having to re-attach delegated event handlers. That's the main principle behind event delegation: you attach handler to a parent element _once_, and wait for events to bubble up from various descendant elements.

Comment: Really your efforts would best be spent fixing the problem that's causing the event handler to be set up when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Anyway to use `.off()` you have to pass in a reference to the exact same function you passed to `.on()`.

Comment: I totally agree. It's something that will be fixed but this is a hot fix in the meantime. I knew this was going to come up. @Pointy  I'll try calling a specific function and reference that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep a reference to the callback function, you can remove all instances of it with [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
var callback = function(){console.log('callback executed');};

jQuery('.moreItems').on('click',callback);
jQuery('.moreItems').on('click',callback);

jQuery('.moreItems').off('click',callback);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeeLza0z/1/)

Comment: Great solution. I found I can also just create a function with the name
`function callback(){ console.log('callback executed');};` and it works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question.

```
$(document).on('click','.moreItems', function(event) {
   ... do stuff ....
});
```

You delegate the click event to document. If you add dynamically elements with class 'moreItems', the click event has been binded automatically.

See the official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Never do this:

- first unbind, next bind
- multiple bind on same element

Answer (score 0):

I will use unbind and bind instead off and on beside I think they are alias of the same function, also append the event to the object, not to the document itself, but that should be optional.

```
$('.moreItems').unbind('click').bind('click', function(event) {
   //Your code
});
```

When you call unbind with only the event type as parameter, it will remove all the handlers of that event, I guess that's also what you want.

Comment: I believe those are being depreciated. Thanks though.

Comment: It is not deprecated, they just mention in the documentation some the differences between on and bind (seem they are not alias after all).
But if you prefer to use on and off, you can just replace them:

$('.moreItems').off('click').on('click', function(event) { /*code*/});

even:

$('.moreItems').off('click').click(function(event) { /*code*/}); 

Click is the shortcut of on('click', ...)

As an advice, jQuery returns the object itself almost in all the method, so link them is more efficient than calling jQuery again in the next line.